# Access Java code from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Hello I'm developing a Java web application on Eclipse using servlets in tomcat 8.

How can I access in one of the `.jsp` pages `java` instances onclick?

The onclick event will be triggered by the user and I need to change the value of a variable in my Java code.

The onclick will have a `unique id` which I will use to change the info on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. Let's go with the basic one.
Your jsp page should have an HTML `form` tag that will enclose the element that will fire the click event.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="https://myip/app/myjsp.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="clickValue" id="clickValue"/>
            <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="fireClick('<%= uniqueVal %>')" id="btn1"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function fireClick(uniqueID){
                    document.getElementById('clickValue').value=uniqueID;
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                }
            </script>
        </form>
        <% String passedValue = request.getParameter("clickValue")%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course, this is the most simple way to do so, many things to be considered with modern web development like using AJAX and even to use a java web framework or JSF.

fiddling : https://jsfiddle.net/w3rhceg2/

Comment: I dont see how i can change the variable in my java object with this

Comment: I updated the answer to read the value sent when the user clicks and save it into a variable in the servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Make an `ajax` request to your servlet.

Comment: Maybe you could also tell how to do that?